# Java Webdriver - Error in TestNG Report

Tags: java, excel, selenium

I use eclipse/TestNG with webdriver to automate a website.

I import data from excel into scripts i.e. no hardcoded values in scripts.

My class has following structure and when I run the program, it works well but give me error in report if excel has data in one row only.

```
 @Test(dataProvider = "Data1")
 public void ABC(String baseurl, String username, String password, String title) {
//code
```

}

```
     @DataProvider(name = "Data1")
     public Iterator<Object[]> data1() throws DataDrivenFrameworkException {
     String excelResource = System.getProperty("user.dir")
                  + System.getProperty("file.separator") + "resources"
                  + System.getProperty("file.separator") +"ABC.xlsx";
     ExcelFile excelFile = new ExcelFile(excelResource);
     excelFile.setSheetName("Sheet1");
     excelFile.setTestCaseHeaderName("TestCaseNameColumn");
     List<List<String>> data = excelFile.getDataUsingTestCaseName("ABC");
     return SeleniumTestNGHelper.toObjectArrayIterator(data);
```

Results:

```
Pass: ABC(http://testsite.com, admin, test, Sample Title) // Excel Row 1 Data
Fail: ABC("", "", "", "")
```

I think the webdriver is using second row as well which has no data mentioned. When I add data in more than one row of excel, it works fine and doesn't fail method like Fail: ABC("", "", "", "")

Thank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have set value/s in that row, and just delete the content of the cells, the data provider will send that row.
You have to delete that row with the 'delete row' option.